# Output a custom YAML preamble witn RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'd like to output my own YAML header in RMarkdown with Markdown output. The reason behind this is the dynamic creation of MD files from a given source.

To attempt to add it with `results='asis'` won't work as it will process the output for links, i.e: add <> to the links:

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  md_document:
    variant: markdown
    toc: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r testyaml, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
h <- "
+++\n
showonlyimage = false\n
draft = false\n
image = \"http://adsf.com\" \n
date = \"2016-11-05T18:25:22+05:30\"\n
title = \"mytitle\"\n
weight = 0\n
+++\n"

cat(h, sep = " ", fill = FALSE, collapse = '\n')
````

Output:

```
+++

showonlyimage = false

draft = false

image = "<http://adsf.com>"

date = "2016-11-05T18:25:22+05:30"

title = "mytitle"

weight = 0

+++
```

(Notice the <> wrapping `http://adsf.com`).

Comment: This seems like a scenario where Parameterized reports would be better suited: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/parameterized-reports.html

Comment: Thanks @MikeyHarper, indeed I use them in the real code. But can't possibly generate raw content for an autogenerated preambule because of the aforementioned `<>` wrapping and either can execute R code in the yaml preamble if I go with `preserve_yaml: true`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `preserve_yaml: true`, like this:

```
output:
  md_document:
    variant: markdown
    preserve_yaml: true
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but that would be adding a whole bunch of extra entries beyond the ones I need and not exactly in the format I need. Also, they can't be dynamic which defeats my goal.